# Knp Menu Bundle Current item Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, menu, knpmenubundle

I have a question regarding rendering the KnpMenu Bundle for Symfony2.
From I've read, there should be a "current" class at the matched route item. I've read the Knp documentation and they're saying something about RouteVoter but I can't make it working. Any ideas?

Builder code:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Menu/Builder.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class Builder extends ContainerAware
{
    public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

        $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'index'));
        $menu->addChild('About Me', array('route' => 'products'));

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, apparently this solution seems to be working:
https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/issues/122#issuecomment-6563863

Answer (score 5):

It's 10 months on and I followed the solution outlined above, however I found it to be convoluted. I use the following method.

```
class Builder extends ContainerAware
{
    public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root');
        // Manually set the current URI.
        $menu->setCurrentUri($this->container->get('request')->getRequestUri());
        // ... 
    }
}
```

I've turned a blind eye to semantics, but what wrong with an approach like the above code sample? 
Please provide feedback as required.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I've been looking for something like this. I hope, one day, the KnpMenuBundle 2.x would be stable and we would be able to use the voters.

Comment: Following the guide of KnpMenuBundle for using the menu as service, the container is not longer needed. You can get the request by scoping the service to the request scope.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this workaround fails in some cases. For example, when using pagination.

Comment: @NikolaPetkanski  is there a solution to add the ``current`` class to the active page link? or should we still use this workaround above?

Comment: Back in the days I was unable to find a working solution, so I ended up implementing my own method for setting the active menu item. What I basically did was to use consistent naming of the routes and string compare the name of current route.

Currently there's a alpha tag for the knpmenu bundle 2.0 - you can try that one.